# Re-enabling Third Party Entries Not Working after Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, ppa, 17.04

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME. Just upgraded from 16.10 to 17.04, I open Software & Updates, and every time when I click on the box to recheck the PPAs, it won't check, and jump to the top of the list by itself.

Comment: Could you explain what this means: "it won't check, and jump to the top of the list by itself."

Comment: When click on the box, it won't show the tick, and jump to the top of the list. http://imgur.com/a/AvaTK

Comment: Thanks, that graphic made it clear. Please edit your question to include the graphic.